# Plotting barplot with two columns with 17 observations

Tags: r, bar-chart

I have a data frame with two columns with 17 observations:

[image]

I've tried the following code:

```
> barplot(my_data$Value, my_data$Question)
```

but it returns this error:

```
# Error in width/2 : non-numeric argument to binary operator
# In addition: Warning message:
# In mean.default(width) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

And when I force a data frame, it produces a barplot with all of the values stacked on one bar, instead of each row being represented by one bar.

It's driving me crazy!

Comment: please include your data using the `dput()` command so we can reproduce this and help you out easier

Comment: what are you trying to plot? A side by side barplot or stacked?

Comment: I'd like a side-by-side barplot

Comment: If you don't mind using ggplot2, you can use: `DF %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Question, y=Value)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity")`

Comment: barplot(my_data$Value,names.arg =my_data$Question), the axis labels are going to ugly though. barplot(my_data$Value,names.arg =my_data$Question,horiz =TRUE)

Comment: I ended up using ggplot(my_data, aes(x=Question, y=Value)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")

Comment: @StupidWolf can't the axis titles be tilted?

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
barplot(DF$Value, names=DF$Question)
```

or

```
barplot(DF$Value, names=DF$Question, horiz=TRUE, las=1)
```

or

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(DF, aes(x=Question, y=Value)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") +
    theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90)) # Play with the angle
```

Comment: It defines the aesthetics for the plot. You specify a variable from the data frame which will permeate through all ggplot functions in the command.